# Generate nice-looking spreadsheets from TFS

Tags: .net, version-control, tfs

We manage our sprints and tasks using TFS (in Visual Studio 2012 and online at visualstudio.net). I can't seem to find any way to generate a report.

I would like to generate an Excel spreadsheet (or at least something) that has hours worked, hours planned, sprint start date, end date, etc. for people to download and see how we're doing each sprint.

Is this even possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Excel add-in that is installed with Team Explorer to generate that information. There are instructions on the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).